# Can I downgrade NuGet extension installed in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, nuget, teamcity

Is it possible to downgrade the NuGet extension in Visual Studio from the latest 3.4.4.1321 to something pre-3.4?

In "Extensions and Updates" in Visual Studio, I can only choose to uninstall the NuGet extension, and if I don't already have it installed the only option is to install the latest verison.

The NuGet extension version I currently have installed with Visual Studio 2015 is not compatible with an internal NuGet feed I'm using.

Specifically, NuGet 3.4 comes with version number normalization which treats version 1.0.0.0 as the same version number as 1.0.0. Unfortunately, the NuGet feed in TeamCity does not, which means that it's impossible to install NuGet packages with the version number ending with .0.

TeamCity tells Visual Studio that the version number is 1.0.0.0. Visual Studio then normalizes this to 1.0.0 and attempts to download package version 1.0.0 from the TeamCity nuget feed, but TeamCity responds that this package version does not exist.

Comment: Matt's suggestion is correct, I test it in my side, it works well. You could uninstall the new version, and then install the old version. If it help you resolve this issue, please mark Matt's reply as the answer:)

Answer (score 2):

You can get older versions of the NuGet Package Extension for Visual Studio from the [NuGet distributions page](http://dist.nuget.org/index.html).

Much older NuGet Package Extensions for Visual Studio 2013 are available from [CodePlex](https://nuget.codeplex.com/releases).